# Why do I get a connection error trying to connect to mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, mean-stack

Doing an excercise, I have to build an application that allows to register users and edit them. I follow the instructions of the book however still i am stuck, because i get an error:

> Unhandled rejection MongoError: cannot connect to server
>       at Collection.listIndexes (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1732:11)
>       at indexInformation (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1607:25)
>       at Db.indexInformation (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1571:44)
>       at ensureIndex (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1066:8)
>       at Db.ensureIndex (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1042:44)
>       at ensureIndex (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1802:13)
>       at Collection.ensureIndex (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1790:44)
>       at tryCatcher (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:11:23)
>       at ret [as ensureIndexAsync] (eval at  (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promisify.js:184:12),
>   :13:39)
>       at MongoStore.setAutoRemoveAsync (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:123:40)
>       at MongoStore.handleNewConnectionAsync (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:116:18)
>       at MongoStore (/home/mihaly/meanbook/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:95:26)
>       at Object. (/home/mihaly/meanbook/CH26/auth_server.js:20:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>       at startup (node.js:136:18)
>       at node.js:966:3

here is how my file looks like...

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({session: expressSession});
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/user_model.js');
var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp');
var app = express();
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'SECRET',
  cookie: {maxAge: 60*60*1000},
  store: new mongoStore({
      db: mongoose.connection.db,
      collection: 'sessions'
    })
  }));
require('./routes')(app);
app.listen(8080);
```

I think i've installed all the necessary modules, and mongo is running. Does anyone know where i made the mistake?

Comment: What happens if you add the port to the connection string. And have you tried to connect to mongod using the shell?

Comment: mongod works fine and is waiting for a connection on standard port 27017. I think the error arises when creating the "new mongostore" because actually i connect to the database at first and the program gets stuck only later on.

Comment: Unlikely: `cannot connect to server ` So you have connected using the shell?